# WSO2 WSF PHP WSClient parse only a part of the message

Tags: php, tcp, client, wso2, wsh

I'm having, what I think, the same problem at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSFPHP-459
The problem is on the client, because sniffing the packets I realize that the message arrives complete. But when the WSClient parse it, it's only gets the first part of the message. The client chunk the message exactly when the tcp packet ends. On the other hand, this happens randomly, and doesn't happens when the message is really short (fits in a tcp packet)

Someone have this issue?

This is the environment where occurs:

**Client:**

CentOS release 5.7
kernel 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5 x86_64
PHP 5.3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr 11 2011 16:08:24)

wsf

wsf support => enabled
wsf version => 2.1.0

nginx version: nginx/1.0.8

**Server:**

CentOS release 6.3
kernel 2.6.32-279.el6.i686
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2013 20:21:47)

wsf

wsf support => enabled
wsf version => 2.1.0

apache: Apache/2.2.15